# Unable to load private Nuget packages in MAC VisualStudio

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, nuget-package

First of all I am able to use the same private nugget package in Windows VisualStudio2022 but not in MacBook.

What I tried:-

Has used the PAT method,
Also used the SetApikey method,

I am not able to figure what I am missing can anyone please help me out of this.
[image]

Comment: do you still have this problem? for me still not working

Comment: It get resolved, I just forgot to change the url to azure configs for packages in mac.